# How to solve Tortoise racing

Tags: java

There is a problem called: Tortoise racing.

The question is:

Two tortoises named A and B must run a race. A starts with an average speed of 720 feet per hour. Young B knows she runs faster than A, and furthermore has not finished her cabbage.

When she starts, at last, she can see that A has a 70 feet lead but B's speed is 850 feet per hour. How long will it take B to catch A?

More generally: given two speeds v1 (A's speed, integer > 0) and v2 (B's speed, integer > 0) and a lead g (integer > 0) how long will it take B to catch A?

The result will be an array [hour, min, sec] which is the time needed in hours, minutes and seconds (round down to the nearest second) or a string in some languages.

> If v1 >= v2 then return nil, nothing, null, None or {-1, -1, -1} for
>   C++, C, Go, Nim, [] for Kotlin or "-1 -1 -1".

Examples:
(form of the result depends on the language)

> race(720, 850, 70) => [0, 32, 18] or "0 32 18"
>
> race(80, 91, 37)   => [3, 21, 49] or "3 21 49"

I tried to solve it like this:

```
  public static int[] race(int v1, int v2, int g) {

            int v3 = v2 - v1;
            double time = (double )g / (double)v3;
            int result[] = new int[3];

            if (v2 > v1) {
                if (time > 1) {
                    while (time > 10) {
                        time /= 10;
                    }
                    result[0] = (int) time;
                    result[1] = (int) ((time - result[0]) * 60);
                    result[2] = (int) ((((time - result[0]) * 60) - result[1]) * 60);
                    System.out.print(result[0] + " " + result[1] + " " + result[2]);
                } else {
                    result[0] = 0;
                    result[1] = (int) (time * 60);
                    result[2] = (int) (((time * 60) - result[1]) * 60);
                    System.out.print(result[0] + " " + result[1] + " " + result[2]);
                }
            }
            else {
                return null;
            }

            return result;
        }
```

but it keeps failing on test cases, could you please help me?

Comment: Why do you use an array to model the time? And why do you use the cast (and back) from int to double? And why don't you just step one second per loop?

Comment: Because I want to get the first digit from the time this will be hours, then subtract the hours from the time and multiply it by 60 to convert it to minutes

Comment: And what unit is the speed in? Ie what does 850 mean? Feet per hour?

Comment: Why do you need `while (time > 10) { time /= 10; }`?

Comment: You don't need a loop to solve a mathematical equasion ;) write the formula and calculate the result in one line

Comment: _"but it keeps failing on test cases"_ - Please provide explicit details on the testcases that fail and explain what debugging you have already done. Did you step through the code in your IDE debugger?  What did you find?

Comment: I used the loop to get the first digit of the time, that digit will be the hours.

Comment: @JimGarrison It runs on the test cases on the website ... But when trying to submit the solution it fails on other test cases that the website doesn't show them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check Below code :

```
public class Tortoise {
    public static int[] race(int v1, int v2, int g) {
        if (v1 >= v2)
            return null;
        int seconds = (g * 3600) / (v2 - v1);
        return new int[]{seconds / 3600, (seconds % 3600) / 60, seconds % 60};
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Tortoise.race(720, 850, 70);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help mate.

Answer (score 2):

Probably you could try following code,

```
public static int[] race(int v1, int v2, int g){
    if(v1 >= v2)
        return null; //B will never catch A
    int speedDifference = (v2 - v1);
    int resultInSeconds = g * 3600 / speedDifference; //*3600 to get in seconds
    int[] result = {resultInSeconds/3600, resultInSeconds%3600/60, resultInSeconds%3600%60};
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I appreciate it.